# What is the difference between POSIX sockets and BSD sockets?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, terminology

Could someone please explain the differences between POSIX sockets and BSD sockets?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As reported in http://www.openss7.org/papers/strsock/sockimp.pdf:

> **Berkeley Sockets**. Sockets uses the BSD interface that was developed by
>   BBN for the TCP/IP protocol suite
>   under DARPA contract on 4.1aBSD and
>   released in 4.2BSD. BSD Sockets
>   provides a set of primary API
>   functions that are typically
>   implemented as system calls. The BSD
>   Sockets interface is non-standard,
>   operated diﬀerently from the POSIX
>   interface in subtle ways, and is now
>   deprecated in favour of the POSIX/SUS
>   standard Sockets interface.
>
> **POSIX Sockets**. Sockets were standardized by X/Open, later the
>   OpenGroup, and IEEE in the POSIX
>   standardization process. They appear
>   in XNS 5.2 [XNS99], SUSv1 [SUS95],
>   SUSv2 [SUS98] and SUSv3 [SUS03].
>   POSIX/SUS Sockets is now the common
>   application environment for accessing
>   networking, deprecating the XTI for
>   TCP/IP networking applications.

Comment: You've marked this as a quote - but not stated where you got the quote from.  You can't have an up-vote until you've shown your source.

Comment: www.openss7.org/papers/strsock/sockimp.pdf

Comment: I am sorry: I was looking at the PDF file through another site, and I was not sure which was the correct URL to report. The PDF file is the one hosted at the address I reported.

Answer (score 8):

bsd sockets is the name for the sockets interface that was first released with the bsd operating system in '83.

later this was rolled up into the posix specification with some more detailed operating specs.

There is no difference except that the term bsd sockets encompasses the api released with the bsd operating system, while the posix standard applies to any os that wishes to be posix compliant.